# How to add focus on the searchbar and open the keyboard when user hit search icon?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3

When I click on search icon, it opens up the search box on the bar, but I want it to focus on the field and open the keyboard.

How do I achieve this ?

Please find below my `home.html` and `home.ts` code

**home.html**

```
<ion-header>
  <ion-navbar color="primary">
    <button *ngIf="!toggled" ion-button icon-only menuToggle><ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon></button>
    <!-- Title -->
    <ion-title *ngIf="!toggled">In&iacute;cio</ion-title>
    <!-- Search Bar -->
    <ion-searchbar *ngIf="toggled" [(ngModel)]="searchTerm" [showCancelButton]="true" (ionCancel)="toggleSearch()" (ionInput)="triggerInput($event)"></ion-searchbar>
    <!-- Search Icon -->    
    <ion-buttons end *ngIf="!toggled">
      <button ion-button icon-only (click)="toggleSearch()"><ion-icon name="search"></ion-icon></button>
    </ion-buttons>  
  </ion-navbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content padding>

<ion-list>
  <ion-item *ngFor="let item of items">
    {{ item }}
  </ion-item>
</ion-list>
</ion-content>
```

**home.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NavController, NavParams } from 'ionic-angular';

@Component( {
    selector: 'page-home',
    templateUrl: 'home.html'
})
export class HomePage {

    toggled: boolean;
    searchTerm: String = '';
    items: string[];

    constructor( public navCtrl: NavController, public navParams: NavParams ) {
        this.toggled = false;
        this.initializeItems();        
    }

    ionViewDidLoad() {
        console.log( 'ionViewDidLoad HomePage' );
    }

    toggleSearch() {
        this.toggled = this.toggled ? false : true;
    }

    initializeItems() {
        this.items = ['Amsterdam','Bogota','Mumbai','San José','Salvador']; 
     }    

    triggerInput( ev: any ) {
        // Reset items back to all of the items
        this.initializeItems();
        // set val to the value of the searchbar
        let val = ev.target.value;
        // if the value is an empty string don't filter the items
        if (val && val.trim() != '') {
          this.items = this.items.filter((item) => {
            return (item.toLowerCase().indexOf(val.toLowerCase()) > -1);
          })
        }  
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I solve this problem that:

1. Import **Searchbar** and **ViewChild**:

```
    import { Searchbar } from 'ionic-angular';
    import { ViewChild  } from '@angular/core';
```

2. Define Searchbar:

```
    export class HomePage {

        @ViewChild('searchbar') searchbar:Searchbar;

        ... some code

    }
```

3. And set focus him:

```
    toggleSearch() {
        setTimeout(() => {  
            this.searchbar.setFocus();
        }, 5);
    }
```

4. In HTML add **#searchbar** flag like this:

   `<ion-searchbar #searchbar ...some code...></ion-searchbar>`

See [more](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/focus-the-ion-searchbar-on-ionviewdidenter/100193) on ionic forum

Comment: <ion-header>
          <ion-toolbar border-top>
            <ion-searchbar  [(ngModel)]="searchTerm"
            #Searchbar
            [showCancelButton]="shouldShowCancel" placeholder="Search for a item" (ionInput)="SearchItem($event)"></ion-searchbar>
          </ion-toolbar>
        </ion-header> 

import { Searchbar} from 'ionic-angular';

  @ViewChild('Searchbar') myInput: Searchbar;

   this.myInput.setFocus();

Set focus is not working here

Comment: not working setFocus undefined after click search bar?